# Fastapi sqlalchemy pydantic relational field

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I am just a starter in FastAPI/Pydantic & SqlAlchemy - I have two model Post and Category where I want Post should fetch Category name instead of only id

when I try to use the below code it gives following error in console

Any help in solving this is much appreciated thank you!

```py
response -> 1 -> category_name
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

**post.py models**

```py
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__="post"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title=Column(String(50))
    user_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("category.id"))
    category_name=relationship("Category", backref="post")


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__="category"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

**Pydantic models**

```py
class CategoryGet(BaseModel):
    id:int
    name:str

    class Config:
        orm_mode=True



class Post(BaseModel):
     
    id = int
    title=str
    user_id=int
    category_id = int
    category_name=CategoryGet 

    class Config:
        orm_mode=True
```

**My mainapp.py**

```py
router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/", response_model=List[schemas.VehicleGet])
def get_vehicle(db: Session = Depends(get_db), skip: int = 0, limit: int = 50) -> Any:
    vehicle = crud.post.get_multi(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return vehicle
```

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic models attributes uses `:` instead of `=`

```py
 class Post(BaseModel):
     
    id: int
    title: str
    user_id: int
    category_id: int
    category_name: CategoryGet 

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that, you forgot `orm_mode=True` config for you `Post` model and consequently it is unable to recognize the `category_name` field. I hope this will solve but if not you could check [this](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1334) thread where an example and some clarification about `relationship` handling with `pydantic`.

Comment: that also does not work - I have tried to follow but the link - I guess I have the similar code - but it does not work ! not sure what is the problem